# Post data from Android app to PHP web service

Tags: android, string, http-post, bundle

I encountered a very strange error. The method below is able to post data to my PHP web service and retrieve JSON encoded data only if I define **nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("country", "USA"));** However, if I use the String variable country instead of "USA", I'll get null from my web service. I've checked the value of String country, it is not null. Below is my code

**My String country is defined here:**

```
public class Countries extends SupportMapFragment implements
    LocationListener, LocationSource
{
private GoogleMap map;
private OnLocationChangedListener mListener;
private LocationManager locationManager;
double mLatitude = 0;
double mLongitude = 0;
String country = "";
.......
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           .......
 }
```

**String country get value from previous activity through Bundle object. The value is not null**

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    View root = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle = getArguments();
    if(bundle == null)
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Country is NULL",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else
    {

        country = getArguments().getString("countryName");


    }
    map = getMap();
    return root;
}
```

**This is my Post data method.**

```
    private String postCountryType()
{
    String responseStr = "";

    try
    {
        // url where the data will be posted
        String postReceiverUrl =      "http://.../country.php";

        // HttpClient
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // post header
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postReceiverUrl);

        // add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("country", country));

        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // execute HTTP post request
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

        if(resEntity != null)
        {

            responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();

            // you can add an if statement here and do other actions based
            // on the response
        }

    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return responseStr;
}
```

responsStr returns me null when I use String variable country instead of pass the data "USA"directly into the new BasicNameValuePair.

I've tried modifying the **new BasicNameValuePair("country", country)** to **new BasicNameValuePair("country", country.toString())**, as well as, **new BasicNameValuePair("country", country + "")**
But unfortunately, both tricks didn't work.

**Additional Info**
If I define String country = "USA", however, inside onCreateView, the value "Japan" is actually assigned to country through getArguments. BasicNameValuePair("country", country) will ignore the value "Japan", but uses the original value "USA".

Anyone has any idea about why this weird thing will happen?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I replaced onCreate() with onActivityCreated(). Acoording to the life cycle of fragment, the value of String country will be retrieved before the fragment onActivityCreated().

Answer (score 1):

`country` may not be null, but have you checked if it is the empty string `""`? That is what it's initialized to in your `Countries` class. I would do `Log.d("debugging", country)`, and check LogCat to see what's actually in country at the point that you create the `NameValuePair`.

Comment: Hi Samuel, 1 more thing that I forgot to mention is , when I put Log.d or Log.e or Log.i in my postCountryType() method, nothing will be logged. However, I did run my app in debugging mode, and from there I found out the value of country is "USA", which wasn't null.